# Status : Failure - Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Tags: database, oracle, server

I have got the problem with my Oracle Database Server that give me an error message **Status : Failure - Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found**. 
I am a newbie at using Oracle Database Server. I just found the way how to fix that problem using these code;

```
SELECT * FROM v$resource_limit WHERE resource_name IN ('processes','sessions');
ALTER system SET processes=300 scope=spfile;
```

When I tried it, I got this Query Result
[image]

But when I tried to increase the number of processes/sessions, it did not help me so much.
Does anyone here could help me to fix this problem.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must restart the Oracle RDBMS after `ALTER system SET processes=300 scope=spfile;`